# Is there a way to see a preview (tile view) of all active windows on the Desktop?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, zoom

I would like to know if there is a way to zoom out and preview all the active windows.

Like this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/mac-osx-expose-clone-for-windows-vista/
[image: preview windows]

---

Also, here is a program that does a similar effect, but on Vista: http://insentient.net/

Comment: I'm afraid that I do not understand what you are asking, could you add more details to help us all out.

Comment: I believe on a mac, you can hit a key and it zooms out all the windows kind of like tiles.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/) (Dexpot is a Virtual Desktop Program). After you installed it, go to the Settings -> Controls -> Dexpot Commands -> [Windows Catalog](http://dexpot.de/?id=dexcontrol) and set the desired key combination. When pressing the key combination the active windows will zoom out and you will see a preview of all the open windows on your active desktop. You can also activate the Windows Catalog by double clicking on the tray icon of Dexpot.

Subsequently, you'll see a tile view of the windows on your active desktop:
[image: Dexpot Windows Catalog]

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 provides two features that might help

The first one it to use Alt+Tab, a windows will pop up and you can go through it by keeping Alt pressed and pressing Tab.

[image]

Another feature is to move the mouse pointer to the top of the desktop until a handle is shown

[image]

then drag it down. The re-sized desktop will appear and you can place it on the left or right.

All open active windows will be shown.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 does this by default with alt-tab